# Rewrite a subdomain to a backend proxy whith nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

if have a subdomain on my nginx webserver configuration: sub.mydomain.com

and i have a backend server which listen on port 5000: http://127.0.0.1:5000

is it possible to pass all subdomain calls to the backend?

Like: https://sub.mydomain.com/list to http://127.0.0.1:5000/sub/list

This should work with all methods: POST, PUT, GET, DELETE

**UPDATE:**

when i call my server: https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com

with the following configuration:

```
upstream http_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
}

server_name ~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+)\.mydomain\.com;
```

This does not work (error: 404):

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://http_backend/$subdomain/;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}
```

This works fine:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://http_backend/mysubdomain/;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}
```

When i log the $subdomain variable in the access_log, it seems to be correct.
nginx version: nginx/1.9.15

Answer (score 0):

To pass all subdomains you need to set it in server name by putting dot before domain.

`server_name .mydomain.com;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use variables in proxy_pass. And you can extract part of domain using regexp server name.

```
server {
   server_name ~^(?<sub>[^.]+)\.example\.com;
   # now subdomain of example.com placed to $sub
   # please, note, this rule do not work for http://example.com
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/$sub/;
      # Path part of proxy_par URI will replace path 
      # part of location directive (so / -> /$sub/, /xxxx/ -> /$sub/xxxx/)
   }
}
```

Thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems nginx does not add the $uri to the proxy_pass if i use the $subdomain variable.

The following solution works:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://http_backend/$subdomain/$uri;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}
```